# Заставить использовать индекс в выборке (like '%')

Tags: oracle, индексы, oracle12c

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Воспроизвожу пример:

```
-- drop table tst_idx
-- Создаем таблицу
create table tst_idx
(
    id integer generated as identity primary key,
    int1 integer,
    num1 number,
    str1 varchar2(1000)

);
/

-- Вставляем данные (1 млн строк)
insert into tst_idx 
(int1, num1, str1)
with h as
(
select 
dbms_random.string('U', 20)||dbms_random.string('U', 4) str,
round(dbms_random.value(5, 1000)) v1,
round(dbms_random.value(5, 1000)) v2
from dual
connect by level <= 1000000
)
select v1, v2, str from h;
commit;
/
-- select * from tst_idx
-- Строим индекс по полю str1
create index idx_tst_1 on tst_idx (str1);
/

-- Строим план выборки
-- 1 - Выборка всех записей (почему не используется индекс, ведь значения не уникальны и по одному значению можно сразу выбрать несколько строк)

explain plan for 
select str1 from tst_idx where length(str1) > 5; 
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display); 
/

-- 2 - Выборка записей с нелепым условием
-- Здесь уже используется индекс

explain plan for 
select str1 from tst_idx where str1 like '%'; 
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display); 

-- 3 - Выборка с хинтом
-- Опять индекс не используется

explain plan for 
select /* + index(t idx_tst_1) */ str1 from tst_idx t; 
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Если я буду в запросе использовать выражение like '%' за мной санитары не приедут? )))

Как можно заставить использовать индекс?

Comment: А в чем смысл выражения `str1 like '%'`? Оно же истинно для всех строк, которые не NULL.

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что при таком выражении в запросе мы видим использование индекса (план 2). В остальных планах использование индекса игнорируется.

Comment: Использовать индекс при выборке более 50% строк не эффективно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут вроде бы все понятно. Случай 1:

```
select str1 from tst_idx where length(str1) > 5;
```

У вас индекс по значению поля, а вы фильтруете по длине строки. Чтобы тут использовался индекс, вам как минимум нужно сделать его function-based (по значению функции `length(str1)`), а кроме того, нужно еще соответствующее распределение данных. Если у вас все строки будут одной длины, то этот индекс тоже не будет никогда использоваться.

Случай 2.

```
select str1 from tst_idx where str1 like '%';
```

Вы выбираете только поле `str1` - оно хранится в индексе. Фильтруете по условию `str1 like '%'` - то есть выбираете только значения из индекса. Довольно логично, что он используется.

Случай 3.

```
select /* + index(t idx_tst_1) */ str1 from tst_idx t;
```

Вы выбираете все строки. Значения в них могут быть `NULL`, а `NULL` в индексе не хранится. Потому и индекс не используется.

Так что оракл все делает правильно. Если вкратце, тут важно помнить две вещи:

1. Что именно и как хранится в индексе (документация вам в помощь)
2. Индекс используется тогда, когда из него выбрать быстрее, чем из самой таблицы.

Comment: А в этом случае? explain plan for 
select distinct str1 from tst_idx t; 
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);            Здесь же легче выбрать по индексу, а он не используется. Или просто select * from tst_idx - должен использоваться индекс для ускорения выборки?

Comment: В вашем индексе, в том виде, в каком вы его создали, содержатся только `NOT NULL` значения поля `str1`. Поэтому: `select distinct str1 from tst_idx t;` - здесь может оказаться `NULL`, а его в индексе нет; `select * from tst_idx` - то же самое, плюс вы выбираете все поля, а не только `str1`. И вообще, запросы вида `select * from table` без условий всегда будут выбираться без индекса.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало понятнее. Не смог найти как создать индекс с учетом null- значений. Не ткнете?

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст function-based index с функцией, которая вместо `NULL` возвращает какое-то значение, которого нет и не будет никогда. Сами разберетесь?

Comment: Уже понял, спасибо, Дмитрий. Буду разбираться ))